# How to setup Topic in HornetMQ on jboss 6

Tags: java, jboss, jms

In hornetmq-jms.xml i see

```
<queue name="ExpiryQueue">
      <entry name="/queue/ExpiryQueue">
</queue>
```

but how to configure a topic?

in jboss 3.2.1 we did it throght `jbossmq-destinations-service.xml`

Comment: Have you tried `<topic name="...">` ?

Answer (score 2):

Download the HornetQ binary distribution and look at the 'topic' example.   The file `examples/jms/topic/server0/hornetq-jms.xml` contains this:

```
<!--the topic used by the example-->
<topic name="exampleTopic">
  <entry name="/topic/exampleTopic"/>
</topic>
```

There are many other examples.   Please up-vote if you find this useful.